# Will Expo OTA updates work with new libraries?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, libraries

I am looking into [Expo OTA Updates](https://docs.expo.io/bare/updating-your-app/) and realizing how crucial it is for production builds on standalone apps.

I am wondering though, this seems to be a good fix for minor JavaScript changes to your app, what if you publish an update having added new library's and dependencies?

Will I have to build another binary for my standalone app or will `expo publish` take care of that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After testing this out, it seems that any additions to new libraries does work.

I did notice you need a new build if you change project files like `app.json` for example.

Comment: Did you try this with JS only libraries or libraries that also had updates to native pieces? I think this would only work with JS only library updates.

Comment: You may be right. I was only able to test this with JS libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the update only involves changes to the JS bundle, and not the native binaries, you should be fine. If the library is pure JS, the update will work. If the library has both a native and JS side to it, the update will be fine as long as the update is only to the JS side. If the native side changed, it won't work.

This article goes into a bit more: [How To Use React Native Over The Air (OTA) Updates](https://pagepro.co/blog/react-native-over-the-air-updates/)